# Boolean mask Tensorflow, tf.boolean_mask - Maintain dimensions of original tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask

I have a 1d `tensor` and a 1d array of `Booleans` of the same length.

I would like to use the Boolean array as a mask on the tensor, such that True keeps the original element-value in the tensor and False sets the original element-value in the tensor to zero.

E.g.

```
Tensor = [1,2,3,4,5]
Array = [True, False, False, False, True]
```

Apply Boolean mask to tensor:

```
Desired result = [1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
Result with tf.boolean_mask = [1, 5]
```

I have tried to use `tf.boolean_mask(tensor, array)`, however, this reduces the dimensions of the resulting tensor to include only `True` elements, 2 dimensions in the above example.

How can I apply a Boolean mask to a tensor while maintaining the original dimensions of the tensor?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tf.where`:

```
tf.where(array, tensor, tf.zeros_like(tensor))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your boolean mask to a `tf.int32` tensor and use `tf.multiply`:

```
mask = tf.constant([True, False, False, False, True])
A = tf.range(1,6)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   res = sess.run( \
          tf.multiply(A, tf.cast(mask, tf.int32)) \
         ) # [1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```